# Why isn't schema.rb formatted correctly in rails 5.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Previously schema.rb was a good place to quickly see what column defaults were and whether or not they could be nullable, but now it's messy. For example, here is a user table:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",                              null: false
  t.string   "email",                             null: false
  t.string   "locale",          default: "en-ca", null: false
  t.string   "password_digest",                   null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

And now it looks horrible like this:

```
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", null: false
  t.string "email", null: false
  t.string "locale", default: "en-ca", null: false
  t.string "password_digest", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end
```

Why did this happen and how can I fix it while keeping the good changes, like `id: :serial` and implicit `btree`?

Answer (score 7):

It was changed on purpose in [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/df84e9867219e9311aef6f4efd5dd9ec675bee5c?short_path=1ed2907#diff-e0d63791fb8e00fc467e7c47b74fb6d6) commit.

Because I look at schema.rb at least 50 times a day to see this type of information I'm going to write a tool later tonight to format it nicely while retaining the positive changes.

I'll post a link to it here once it's ready. Bug me here if I forget to post it.

Edit:

I created the script, but it's pretty brittle. I'm transforming the string output to new string output and I'm not confident I've hit all the edgecases. <strike>If you want to risk it reach out to me and I'll give you the current working version of the rake task, but it's not exactly great.</strike>

**Edit2:**

**I've been using [my hacky script](https://gist.github.com/zachaysan/c0e431838615d6e1cfc36275bff5fe4a) for some time now without issue. If you want to add it to your project, feel free to copy it into a rake task.**

Edit3:

I've switched to a SQL schema because it better encompasses what we generally want when working in production / testing. I still wanted to read the schema.rb while developing though so what I did was the following, which is working great and is less risky:

```
# In config/application.rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql


# In config/environments/development.rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :ruby

# In the rake task
namespace :db do

  def cleanup_schema
    # Other code goes here
  end

  task :migrate do
    if Rails.env.development?
      cleanup_schema
    end
  end

  task :rollback do
    if Rails.env.development?
      cleanup_schema
    end
  end

  task :cleanup_schema do
    cleanup_schema
  end

end
```

Comment: You may also be interested in https://github.com/jakeonrails/fix-db-schema-conflicts which we've used for a long time to alphabetically sort the schema and standardize the indentation.